# Making navigation behave same way with mouse hover

Tags: jquery

I  am trying to make my navigation more accesssible that is, it should work with tab key. The idea is that everything with the inner div is hidden on page load and,  on hover or focus on any of the Test anchors, the corresponding div should appear.

I am able to get the hover to work without jquery, that is with just CSS. However, i cannot do the same for focus.

So i decided to write a bit of jquery but i am quite getting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span><a href="">Test 1</a></span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><a href="">Test 2</a></span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><a href="">Test 3</a></span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


.nav ul li {float: left;}
.nav ul li div {position:absolute; left: -999px;}


$('.nav ul li span a').focus(function(){
    $('.nav ul li div').css({'left': '0'});
}).focusout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following works:

```
<style>
.nav ul li {float: left;}
.nav ul li div {position:absolute; display:none;}​
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.nav ul li span a').on("focus mouseenter", function(){
      $(".nav div").hide();
      $(this).parent().siblings("div").show();
   });

   $(".nav ul li").on("mouseleave", function(){
      $("div",this).hide();
   });
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/ArU6j/

First up, use `display:none` rather than `left: -999px` otherwise the tab key lets you tab through the fields that are "invisible" off the edge of the screen.

Then, when the mouse is moved over one of the top level anchor elements, or one of them gets focus, we hide any previous sub-menu that was visible and show the one applicable to the current anchor.

We do *not* hide the sub-menu when the anchor loses focus, because then you can't tab to the items in the sub-menu.

Finally, when the mouse is moved off a parent li element we hide its sub-menu - we don't do this on mouseleave from the top level anchor because then you couldn't get the mouse to the sub-menu before it disappears.

(There's at least one minor problem with the above, but it should get you started.)